# IP Address leak on LAN scan

Tags: vpn, ip, spoofing, lan

I am using VPN and encrypting my web traffic through them. However, When I do Lan Scan I can see my real ip address. All other websites, IPleak.net, WebRTC leaks, DNS leak, Email Leak and IPv6 leak do not reveal my real IP address, which is safe. However, if anyone use packet sniffing or do a Lan Scan shall see real Ip address. What can I do to hide that or that is not possible ? I am using OS X (Mac). Apple Firewall is turned on.

Any ideas or suggestions what to do ?

Comment: What is a "LAN Scan"?

Comment: A LAN scan can have multiple levels of deep-ness starting with simple ICMP sweep. Various tools may detect LAN IPs at various levels. Your question is too broad.

Comment: Is there a way to avoid being detected on LAN Scan ? I am not sure if its ICMP. I am using LanScan from Apple app store.

Comment: when you do a network scan in your LAN, you most likely don't see your public ip but your private (10.x.x.x, 192.168.x.x, etc.). please read up on the difference if that is the case

Answer (score 1):

As the IP address being visible on the LAN is how your VPN packets get back to you hiding it from other people on the same LAN is a tad hard.  Also normally the point of a VPN for privacy isn't to conceal your IP address from everyone but to make sure that the people who can see your IP address can't see what data you are sending and receiving and people who can see the data can't see your IP address.

Whatever you do the people who administer the LAN will probably be able to tell you are the person using a VPN if they can be bothered to look.  Most techniques that would hide your IP address on the LAN will make you even 
more obvious in some other way.

If you want to hide the fact that you are using a VPN from the LAN admins your best bet is to try and make sure that your VPN looks like normal (eg https or ssh) traffic.  While this isn't too hard to do at a superficial level traffic analysis would probably reveal you.